# Book called "Thunderbird" by an author named Katy about space or flight

Tags: story-identification, novel, space, space-exploration

I read a book called Thunderbird by Katy something I have forgotten her last name. I vaguely remember it being about either space or flying or flying in space.

Comment: Do you remember any more details about the book? When were you in high school? And this is not related to the *Thunderbirds* TV show?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 5):

Any chance you're thinking of *[Thunderbirds are Go!](https://www.alibris.com/Thunderbirds-Are-Go/book/8283631)* by Kitty Richards?

[image: Book cover of *Thunderbirds are Go!*]

> It's not easy being the fourteen-year-old son of a billionaire ex-astronaut. Your older brothers get to fly the super-advanced Thunderbird rescue vehicles, but you're not even allowed to touch the control panels! Now Alan Tracy has the chance to prove he's got what it takes to be a full-fledged Thunderbird. With his family's lives at stake, he must defeat The Hood -- a maniacal villain with an evil plan to destroy the Tracys and their Thunderbirds.

It's an adaptation of the then-upcoming [live-action remake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_(2004_film)) of the supermarionation TV show, *[Thunderbirds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_(TV_series))*.

Comment: Actually that's not it. It had a picture of a guy and a lady at the front of it and The authors name was Katy

Answer (score 5):

I found the book it wasn't Thunderbird but [*Firebird*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23330563-firebird) of the Firebird trilogy. Her name is Kathy Tyers.

> **Her death was expected, but something more powerful kept her alive.**
>
> Lady Firebird was born to the royal family of Netaia. Because of her birthplace in the family, however, her life is expendable. Honorable suicide is the highest calling she could hope to attain. When she is chosen to lead an attack on the neighboring planet of Veroh her death is expected. Instead she is taken prisoner during the battle and is held by the enemy.
>
> With her own people seeking her sacrifice, Firebird must choose between two worlds before she can carve out her new destiny. This is the story of Lady Firebird's personal battle and its eternal consequences, not only for herself but for everyone around her, and especially the man who loves her.

[image: Firebird front cover]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to tell us what this was. You should be able to accept your own answer, please do so!

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.